# How can I get if is in this table 'catalog_product_entity_text' Use Default value on product Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, store-view

In database, I find data like this

> SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` where entity_id = 70430 AND attribute_id = 76 AND store_id = 5;

How can I do it programmatically?

I need info if it is checked Use Default Value on store view for the product.

[image]

This gives me if is the default store view or not.

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Attribute\ScopeOverriddenValue $scopeOverriddenValue
) {
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->scopeOverriddenValue = $scopeOverriddenValue;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
public function translateProducts(){
foreach($products as $product)
        {
            $product_id = $product->getId();
            $p = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setStoreId($store_id)->load($product_id);
            $defaultProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);


            $isOverriden = $this->scopeOverriddenValue->containsValue(
                \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::class,
                $product,
                'name', 
                $store_id                   
            );
            
            $logger->info( "store id: ".$store_id." id: ".$product->getId(). " sku: ".$product->getSku()." Name ". $p->getName()." Default name ". $defaultProduct->getName()." isOverriden: ".$isOverriden. "xxxxx ". $product->getExistsStoreValueFlag("name"));
            
            /*if($isOverriden == 0){*/ //here I want to check if value is override
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento doesn't store any flags like use default

Magento EAV value tables designed with following rules:

- Row with `store_id=0` means default or fallback value
- Row with `store_id=1` means value for store
- If doesn't exists row with `store_id=1` will be used row with `store_id=0` and it's means **Use Default Value**
- Each attribute has own scope and this applicable only for `is_global=0` in `catalog_eav_attribute`

When the system loads product data per store all global values will be replaced to store values if they are present.

In which place are you want to detect the system uses default or store value for attribute and what is the goal?

Anyway, you can use `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Attribute\ScopeOverriddenValue` in any logic on frontend as well.

**[Update]**

The issue with your fragment that you cannot use the same instance of `ScopeOverriddenValue` for different products and you need to use new for each

Just try this code

```
foreach ($this->collection as $product) {
    // instance of \Magento\Catalog\Model\Attribute\ScopeOverriddenValueFactory in __constructor
    $scopeOverriddenValue = $this->scopeOverriddenValueFactory->create();
    $isOverridden         = $scopeOverriddenValue->containsValue(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::class,
        $product,
        'name',
        $storeId
    );

    // you can create single instance of \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product in __constructor
    $productResource = $product->getResource();
    $defaultName     = $isOverridden
        ? $productResource->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(), 'name', 0)
        : $product->getName();

    $message = "store id: " . $storeId . ", product id: " . $product->getId() . ", sku: " . $product->getSku() . ", name: " . $product->getName() . ", default: " . $defaultName . ", overridden: " . ($isOverridden ? 'yes' : 'no');
    $this->logger->info($message);
}
```

Example from log:

```
store id: 1, product id: 8, sku: 10-1-1040, name: Store Value, default: Global value, overridden: yes
```

Comment: I want to translate products in-store view, but if the Use Default value is not checked then translate otherwise exit and check another product.

Comment: Please specify more details about your logic (front\backend) and I can advise best way. Maybe make sense to create some custom resource model with load logic or something else.

Comment: I change the post.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: For all collections, I got the same value: overridden: yes, What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you have populated attribute value on store level for all those products. Ideally to manually setup values for products in tested collection via admin to be sure. Or provide more details. I've tested posted fragment and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

When I use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Attribute\ScopeOverriddenValue was not working correctly, but with this class \Magento\Catalog\Model\Attribute\ScopeOverriddenValue**Factory** everything work as should.

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Attribute\ScopeOverriddenValueFactory $scopeOverriddenValue
) {
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->scopeOverriddenValue = $scopeOverriddenValue;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Comment: It's exactly what I've pointed in answer ;)